# No such table even though db.execSQL(sql) executes without an error

Tags: android, oncreate, sqliteopenhelper

I have a weird issue to work through. The system properly calls the SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() method and it also seems that **db.execSQL(sql)** is successful, but the table is never created.

I'm accessing the VM using "adb devices" >> cd into the /data/data/package/databases >> sqlite3 to run .tables. If I execute "select * from posts" the result is "No such table." Thanks for any guidance.

**EDITED**

I added the MainActivity class to show that I do call .getWritableDatabase(). When I do I can see that the onCreate method is called and there aren't any errors, but when I check to see if the table is there... it isn't.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DnDa";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db-rss.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "posts";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_LINK = "link";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String COLUMN_PUBDATE = "pubdate";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String COLUMN_GUID = "guid";

    private Post post;
    private ArrayList<Post> posts;
    private Cursor cursor;

    /**
     * constructor
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLiteException {
        String sql = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ( %s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT )",
                DATABASE_TABLE, COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_LINK, COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, COLUMN_PUBDATE, COLUMN_CATEGORY, COLUMN_GUID);

        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);
            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully created table: " + sql);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE;
        db.execSQL(sql);

        this.onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        Log.d(TAG, "Opening database");
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all records
     */
    public Cursor getAllRecords(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_PUBDATE, COLUMN_DESCRIPTION}, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "DnDa";

    private String finalUri = "http://wordpress.com/feed/";
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Post post;
    private ArrayList posts;
    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private ListView listView;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


}
```

Comment: This is not how you create a table. Try something like this--> "create table "+DATABASE_TABLE+" ( "+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "... and so on.

Comment: Out of curiosity why would someone mark this question as negative? Did I ask a dumb question? I did many Google searches for a solution before posting my question here.

Comment: while posting questions, you have to be specific of your problem. you should post a code and along with that the error or your logcat. that helps others to answer your question. if you provide correct and full information only then someone can correctly help you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your table is not created.try this `SQL Create Table` Command

```
 String sql = "CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" ( "+
   COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
   COLUMN_TITLE+" TEXT,"+
   COLUMN_LINK+" TEXT,"+
   COLUMN_DESCRIPTION+" TEXT,"+
   COLUMN_PUBDATE+" TEXT,"+
   COLUMNCOLUMN_CATEGORY+" TEXT,"+
   COLUMN_GUID+" TEXT)"

 db.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: I tried both methods to create the sql statement (String and String.format). The .execSQL() method seems to run just fine because it doesn't give me an error, but the table is never created.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `getWritableDatabase()` on the `DatabaseHelper` object? May be you have [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282138/sqlite-database-oncreate-is-not-being-called) like this?

== EDIT ==

I've made a project with your `DatabaseHelper` and this code in `Activity`:

```
DatabaseHelper mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor с = mOpenHelper.getAllRecords(db);
```

works great, cursor contains three columns, no exceptions.

Comment: It's good to know that the code works. I do call the getWritableDatabase method, but no table is created. Do I need to specify a database name?

Answer (score 0):

Ok; I feel like a fool. The table was successfully created every time the code executed. The problem was I ran "sqlite3" without specifying a database. Now that I'm actually managing the right database I can see that the table is there.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html

```
sqlite3 /data/data/<package>/databases/<database-name>.db
```

Thanks again for your contribution and testing my code.